# What does delta has to do with an iteration scheme in a problem about contraction mapping theorem.

Tags: analysis

This is the problem that I'm asked to solve

Set up an iteration scheme to solve $\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}= tx^{2}+ x^{3}, x(0)= 1,$ take $\delta< 1/5$

(That's all)

I know how to set up an iteration and I know the $\delta$ is mentioned in the proof of the theorem, but I don't know why the iteration itself has anything to do with $\delta.$

Comment: You should make explicit what $delta$ is in your question otherwise it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackMath.

Comment: I mean the problem just said take delta < 1/5 without further indication. That's why I came  up and asked. Maybe I should provide that it is a problem after a chapter about the contraction mapping theorem? Thanks though.

Comment: I don't what delta is. The notation in a theorem or proof is not the same in every book or webpage